# how to apply OnFocusChangeListener to a text box?

Tags: java, android, focus

i have a text box in my app, and i want it to have a predefined text, but as user tap on it, it became clear to get input. i mean there is text id text box, text remain there either text box is focused or not, and when text box is empty and not focused show my predefined text.
Thank you veryyyyyyyy much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is a text `hint`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:hint="Team name"
    android:ems="10" >
```

[image]

then when you click on the edit box, the text will go away.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the setHint method or the android:hint attribute.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint